# How do I create a collection like data structure in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm sorta new to PHP (primary experience in Java) and 
I'm trying to create a data structure that holds data in the following format
`Map<String,List<String>>`. The map essentially holds the url as a key and important attributes (of the url) in a list.

The closest data structure that I see in PHP is a 2 dimensional array. But Im not really sure whether it can be extended to my requirements. Any insight or code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$url = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.bing.com', ....];
function getValuesForUrl($url) { return ['...', '...', ...]; }
```

Here is how you would create such a data structure:

```
$var = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $var[$url] = getValuesForUrl($url);
];
```

Note that I am using the short array syntax (`[]`). If you are using PHP < 5.4, replace with `array()`

Comment: The representation indicates, exactly what I was looking for. However, can you explain how I  would create `$var` programatically(rather than hard coded) ? given just  an array with keys and functions that give each of the values.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to observe that most PHP code you will see in the wild will use the array for almost all sorts of data structures. Even modern frameworks stick to that rudimentary but still quite useful construct.

But there are, [native data structure implementations](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php), though.

You will not, however, get the type of strong(and static) typing you desire from Java/C# like you have. PHP is dynamically typed, as you probably already know.

Also check out the [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for more reading